# Which document formats support streamed viewing?

Tags: http, streaming

We are writing an app which will display some documents to the users. These documents can be quite chunky (say 100 pages, 10 MB total size is common). The documents will served by a web app using HTTP.

Of course, we don't want for the users to wait for the whole document to download before they see even the first page. We would like the users start viewing the document as it downloads.

A lot depends on the document format. For example, it could be that MS Word docs must be present in their entirety before we can even show the first page, simply because how the format is structured.

**My question is**: are there document formats (apart from HTML) which support this streamed viewing?  If there are, what are those formats? In particular, I'm interested in these formats and whether they do or don't support streamed viewing:

- MS Word 2003 (.doc)
- MS Word 2010 (.docx)
- PDF
- XPS

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong here but I believe this is a matter of how you design your view. If you design your view so that only part of the document is loaded onto the reasonable sized page/view once the information quantity required to fill the page is downloaded, then as the user browses through pages it will load the information onto the consequent pages, Though that is not to say the rest of the document wont be downloading whilst user is reading the current page. In fact this is probably the best way to mitigate the waiting time of huge documents. With regards to pdf documents I believe there's an API for loading pdf documents that will display it page by page. 
From here on you just need to programmatically set whether or not the view displays the content as it's downloaded or wait for enough information before displaying the view.

Comment: Well it's not exactly about the viewer, it's about file formats. For example, if the file is compressed with an algorithm which requires the whole file to be available (downloaded) before we can uncompress it, then no matter which viewer you have it will have to wait for the whole file before it can display anything.